# unable to show success page after completion of payment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-class-based-views, razorpay

i am using razorpay payment gateway web integration for my learning eccomerce project everyhing work fine payment can be done all i want is to store some information after payment done in my order model using test mode

my views.py for checkout

```
 class Checkout_Pre(View):
        def post (self, request,):
            user = request.user
            address = Address.objects.filter(default=True, user=request.user)
            cart = request.session.get('cart')
            items = Item.get_items_by_id(list(cart.keys()))
            prefer = request.POST.get('payment')
            total_price = request.POST.get('paying_price')
            total_item_price = json.loads(total_price)
            with transaction.atomic():
                order = Order.objects.create(
                        user=user,
                        total_price=total_item_price,
                        address=address.first(),
                        method = prefer,
                        )
                for item in items:
                    item_order = OrderItem.objects.create(
                        order=order,
                        item=item,
                        size=cart.get(str(item.id)),
                        price=item.price,
                        )
                request.session['cart'] = {}   
            order_currency = 'INR'
    
            callback_url = 'http://'+ str(get_current_site(request))+"/handlerequest/"
            print(callback_url)
            notes = {'order-type': "Basic order from the coolbuy website", 'key':'value'}
            razorpay_order = razorpay_client.order.create(dict(amount=total_item_price*100, currency=order_currency, notes = notes, receipt=order.order_id, payment_capture='0'))
            print(razorpay_order['id'])
            order.razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order['id']
            order.save()
               
            return render(request, 'payment/razorpaypaymentsummary.html', {'order':order, 'order_id': razorpay_order['id'], 'orderId':order.order_id, 'final_price':total_item_price, 'razorpay_merchant_id':settings.razorpay_id, 'callback_url':callback_url,})
```

so what the error is after payment completion i want to show html page and change sttus in db but after payment completion the handlerequest throwinh me http 505 error

```
@csrf_exempt
def handlerequest(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            payment_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_payment_id', '')
            order_id = request.POST.get('razorpay_order_id','')
            signature = request.POST.get('razorpay_signature','')
            params_dict = { 
            'razorpay_order_id': order_id, 
            'razorpay_payment_id': payment_id,
            'razorpay_signature': signature
            }
            try:
                order_db = Order.objects.get(razorpay_order_id=order_id)
            except:
                return HttpResponse("505 Not Found")
            order_db.razorpay_payment_id = payment_id
            order_db.razorpay_signature = signature
            order_db.save()
            result = razorpay_client.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
            if result==None:
                amount = order_db.total_amount * 100   #we have to pass in paisa
                try:
                    razorpay_client.payment.capture(payment_id, amount)
                    order_db.payment_status = 1
                    order_db.save()
                    return render(request, 'firstapp/payment/paymentsuccess.html',{'id':order_db.id})
                except:
                    order_db.payment_status = 2
                    order_db.save()
                    return render(request, 'firstapp/payment/paymentfailed.html')
            else:
                order_db.payment_status = 2
                order_db.save()
                return render(request, 'firstapp/payment/paymentfailed.html')
        except:
            return HttpResponse("505 not found")
```

any idea what i am doing wrong here in my handlre request view

order model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, default= True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = status_choices, default=1)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False,)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=False, default=0)
    payment_status = models.IntegerField(choices = payment_status_choices, default=3)
    order_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=200, null=True, default=None) 
    datetime_of_payment = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created_at = models.TimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    razorpay_signature = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + " " + str(self.order_id)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment:
                self.order_id = self.datetime_of_payment.strftime('ORDER%Y%m%dODR') 
                return super(Order,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your view but with the save method of your model.
in the else part you are doing nothing. You should call the super generally.

Please modify the save function as below and then try :

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.order_id is None and self.datetime_of_payment:
        self.order_id = self.datetime_of_payment.strftime('ORDER%Y%m%dODR') 
    return super(Order,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: now throwing me error now i am not even able to save the data

Comment: Method Not Allowed (POST): /PlaceInstantly
Method Not Allowed: /PlaceInstantly
[18/Aug/2021 19:03:32] "POST /PlaceInstantly HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: Method Not Allowed (POST): /PlaceInstantly
Method Not Allowed: /PlaceInstantly
[18/Aug/2021 19:03:32] "POST /PlaceInstantly HTTP/1.1" 405 0

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: i can't This page isn’t workingIf the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405 only showing me this page by the way i added my html and url

Comment: the `order_id` in the model is unique and your order id scheme will give you integrity error unless you place only one order a day.

Comment: i am changed that to ORDER%Y%m%dODR%H%M%S so by sec everone got a uniques id

Comment: Are you able to post the data ?

Comment: no i am not able to when i click to submit it throw me the above mentioned error

Comment: figure out that problem but now all the thing save in that but still handle request not working acc to payment status throwing 505 error after payment completion

Comment: it has to thow me sucess page html

Comment: you have to debug line by line using a debugger as the 505 page is rendered if there is a error in the try catch block and there are nested try catch blocks. Use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace();` right after the first line of handler.

Answer (score 1):

In your post method, after you assign

`order.razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order['id']`

you need to save it. Looks like that's missing.

Comment: i tried order.save() but did not saving in it

Comment: Did you check whether order and orderitem is created in the db? In short, is the atomic_transaction block a success?

Comment: but all the razorpay thing go blank

Comment: Strange! Can you print the value of order before the line `order.razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order['id']`. order_id is unique in your model, but I have a doubt in your save method. Also can you put your atomic transaction code within a try catch block.

Comment: so what you will suggest

Comment: Looking at your comments in the other answer, looks like now things are being saved. To find out why it does not re-direct to success page, print the exception in your main try block, both e.message and type(e) where e is except Exception as e, then you will know what is happening.

Comment: for your effort but i cant offer you bounty thankyou

Answer (score 0):

In your checkout view

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        order = Order.objects.get(pk = self.kwargs['order'])
        settings = SiteSettings.objects.all().first()


        # Razorpay client auth
        client = razorpay.Client(auth = (settings.razorpay_client_id, settings.razorpay_secret))
        
        if order.razorpay_order_id is None:    
            order_amount = order.total*100
            order_currency = settings.currency
            order_receipt = 'Reciept'
            notes = {'id': order.id, 'email': order.email_id, 'date':str(datetime.now()), 'amount': order.total, 'is_ios': order.is_ios, 'is_android': order.is_android}   # OPTIONAL
            data = {"amount":order_amount, "currency":order_currency, "receipt":order_receipt, "notes":notes, "payment_capture":'0'}
            razorpay_order = client.order.create(data = data)

            # Razorpay order inserted into database order
            order.razorpay_order_id = razorpay_order["id"]
            order.save()

        else:
            razorpay_order = client.order.fetch(order.razorpay_order_id)


        return render(request, self.template_name, {'settings':settings, 'order':order, 'razorpay_order': razorpay_order})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        o = self.kwargs['order']+ ' POST'
        
        settings = SiteSettings.objects.all().first()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'settings':settings, 'order':o})
```

In your handler

```
    settings    = SiteSettings.objects.all().first()
    order       = Order.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('order_id'))

    #Razorpay authentication
    client = razorpay.Client(auth = (settings.razorpay_client_id, settings.razorpay_secret))
    
    #Razorpay transaction details
    razorpay_transaction_details = { 
        'razorpay_order_id':    request.POST.get('razorpay_order_id'),
        'razorpay_payment_id':  request.POST.get('razorpay_payment_id'),
        'razorpay_signature':   request.POST.get('razorpay_signature')
    }

    #Razorpay payment verification
    client.utility.verify_payment_signature(razorpay_transaction_details)
        
    #Razorpay capture payment Make sure you change this accordingly.
    payment_transaction_details = client.payment.capture(razorpay_transaction_details['razorpay_payment_id'], order.total*100, {"currency":"payment_currency"})
    order.order_description     = payment_transaction_details
    order.status                = 'paid'
    order.save()


    context = {'request': request.POST, 'order': order, 'settings':settings, 'UserData':UserData, 'Password': Password}

    return render(request, 'web/rpay-success.html', context)
```

You can wrap a try except block in it to render failure.

Comment: i think you didn't payed attention that i am also posting some data in my model so how can i post that data in my model

Comment: and please i am looking for error what the problem in my code

Comment: i don't want to copy someone code i hope you understand

Comment: Hello I do appreciate your choice to not blatantly copy paste, but the code that i have sent is a cookie cutter example about how to do it, the posted code will not work in itself, it only follows the documentation provided by razorpay, you will have to make adjustments according to your business logic.